# Angular custom Pipe declaration

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, angular-pipe

I am trying to use a custom *Pipe* to filter a list of items.

```
// pipes/my-filter/my-filter.ts

import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'my-filter',
})
export class MyFilter implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: string, ...args) {
    return value;
  }
}
```

I would like to use it in a page *Component* that display that list.

```
// pages/mymodule-liste/mymodule-liste.html

<ion-content>
    <ion-searchbar
      placeholder="Find"
      [(ngModel)]="myInput">
    </ion-searchbar>
    <button ion-item *ngFor="let item of listItem | myFilter: myInput"">
</ion-content>
```

I try to import the *Pipe* to the *Component*

```
// pages/mymodule-liste/mymodule-liste.ts

import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MyFilter } from '../../pipes/my-filter/my-filter';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-mymodule-liste',
  templateUrl: 'mymodule-liste.html',
})
export class MymoduleListePage {
  listItem: any
  constructor(
      public navCtrl: NavController,
      public navParams: NavParams,
      public myFilter: MyFilter) {
  }    
}
```

But I get this error:

> Error: Template parse errors: The pipe 'myFilter' could not be found

I also try to declare it as providers in `mymodule-list.module.ts`, or globaly in my `app.modules.ts` declarations and providers but still doesn't work.

I take a look at Angular [documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html) about *Pipe*, as well as other stackoverflow answers but can't find a way to make it work.

So my question is how to declare/register a custom *Pipe* in Angular (v4.1.0) / Ionic (v3.3.0) for use in a specific component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your pipe name is my-filter not myFilter

```
<ion-content>
    <ion-searchbar
      placeholder="Find"
      [(ngModel)]="myInput">
    </ion-searchbar>
    <button ion-item *ngFor="let item of listItem | my-filter: myInput"">
</ion-content>
```

Comment: It would be good practice to rename the pipe to `myFilter` since pipes are used inside of expressions.

Comment: As simple as that. I feel a bit stupid... Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Aluan Haddad I think you're right and I try to rename `my-filter` pipe to `myFilter` but got error: _The pipe 'myFilter' could not be found_. Quite typical with Angular.

Comment: In fact I just realize this is no more the "Angular way" to do this.
The documentation is fairly clear about it, but however I was thinking I could just implement filter pipe like it exists in first version. In fact, I follow advices I found in some other answers to move the logic in the _Component_. But still curious about the naming logic.

Comment: the logic behind using the name `myFilter` instead of `my-filter` is that it is used in the context of Angular _expressions_ used in templates. Such template expressions, used between `{{}}` and in the _values_ of attributes, are _JavaScript like_ (e.g. `n === 1 ? 'one': 'many'`) and should follow its naming conventions. However, Angular itself violates HTML's naming rules by introducing case sensitive attribute _names_. The whole thing is a mess.

Answer (score 0):

The name of your pipe is  `my-filter` not `myFilter`.

Also check if the pipe is registered in ngModule in declerations